# MVC tab page not refreshing nested partialview after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using [jquery tab ui](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax).  My second tab contains this form when posted, does not refresh a partial view I have nested.  What could be the problem?

_Partial_Item_Tab.cshtml

```
@model Mvc5.Models.ORDER_DETAILSMetadata

@{
    var ordernumber = (int)Session["Order_Number"];   
}
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Items", "Order",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "target"
            }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.id)                           
        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />

    }

<div id="target">
    @Html.Action("Items_List", new { id = ordernumber });    <==== This does not show up after postback.  Only after clicking browser refresh button does it show.
</div>
```

Items Controller (HttpPOST)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Items(ORDER_DETAILSMetadata model)
{


        // check to see if exists

        //update order 
        Order order = new Order();
        ....
        return PartialView("_Partial_Item_Tab", order);                


}
```

Item_List Controller

```
    public ActionResult Items_List(int id)
    {

        List<ORDER_DETAILS> result = db.ORDER_DETAILS.Where(p => p.Order_Number == id).ToList();

        return PartialView("_Partial_Items_List", result);

    }
```

Comment: can you show `_Partial_Item_Tab` view?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. The initial view displays the view returned by the `Items_List()` method but when you post you are replacing that with the view returned by the `Items()` method which is a different view. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Stephen, When my tab loads, I have a form that when posted, it should automatically displays a list of new records that was just posted.  That list is _Partial_Items_List.

Comment: @user1929393, Your AjaxForm is posting back to `Items()` which returns the partial view  `_Partial_Item_Tab`. It should be returning the partial view `_Partial_Items_List`, so once you save the new order, get the updated list and return it (as you do in the `Items_List()` method), or  (probably better) return a partial view for just the new order and append it (rather than replace)